# Does clang code formatting utility break defines only on Windows?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clang, clang-format

There is this nice clang [plugin](http://llvm.org/builds/) for VS that supports code formatting. It is nice yet it breaks all complex defines:

Say we had:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#define NM_PP_VARIADIC_MAX_LENGTH 5

#define NM_PP_TYPE_DECL(z, n, T) \
class BOOST_PP_CAT(T, n )

#define NM_PP_TYPE(z, n, T) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(T, n )

#define NM_PP_ARGUMENT_DECL(z, n, T) \
    BOOST_PP_CAT(T, n ) BOOST_PP_CAT(t, n )
```

This is what we get after formating:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#define NM_PP_VARIADIC_MAX_LENGTH 5

#define NM_PP_TYPE_DECL(z, n, T) \
class BOOST_PP_CAT(T, n)

#define NM_PP_TYPE(z, n, T)
BOOST_PP_CAT(T, n)

#define NM_PP_ARGUMENT_DECL(z, n, T)
BOOST_PP_CAT(T, n) BOOST_PP_CAT(t, n)
```

As you can see such code will not compile and most `\`  are removed. Is there a way to configure it to not remove `\`?

I tried using default configurations like LLVM and looked at [formatting arguments](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) but I can not see where such cruel code optimization is defined.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is caused by the file endings used, usually CR+LF in windows. Try to convert your files to unix style line endings (LF) and it should work.